# BigQuery - BI Engine measuring savings

Tags: google-bigquery, gcloud, google-bi-engine

I have deployed BI Engine in one of my Google projects and I am measuring cost savings using the following query

```
with tbl
as
(
    select creation_time, total_bytes_processed, total_bytes_billed,    
           5 * (total_bytes_processed / 1000000000000) as cost_projected, 
           5 * (total_bytes_billed / 1000000000000) as cost_actual

      from `region-us`.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS_BY_PROJECT b
     where 1=1
       and job_type = "QUERY"
       and creation_time >= '2022-05-10 11:30:00.000 UTC'
       and creation_time <= '2022-05-10 19:00:00.000 UTC'
)
select sum(cost_projected) - sum(cost_actual) as savings
  from tbl
 where 1=1
;
```

However, I noticed that very often I have accelerated queries (bi_engine_statistics.bi_engine_mode = 'FULL') for which 'total_bytes_billed = total_bytes_processed'. I was expecting that for accelerated queries total_bytes_billed should be equal to zero which does not seem to be the case.

So the questions are:

1. Is my query the correct way of measuring savings,
2. Is it normal to have fully accelerated queries with total_bytes_billed > 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. To answer your question on **calculation of savings**:
   I think it is the correct way of measuring your savings, but some queries of type `QUERY` cannot be used for BI Engine, so it's somewhat unfair to keep counting them in.
   Which is why I wrote the script in this SO question:
   [BigQuery BI Engine: how to choose a good reservation size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74743376/bigquery-bi-engine-how-to-choose-a-good-reservation-size)
   Also you could improve on converting bytes to TB by calculating as follows:
   `sum(total_bytes_processed) / pow(1024, 4) AS TB_processed`

2. As for your **question on FULL mode and still having to pay**:
   I have turned BI Engine on and if I run this query on my data, I get 0 results, so all my `bi_engine_mode='FULL'` queries have savings:

```sql
SELECT 
    total_bytes_processed, 
    total_bytes_billed, 
    bi_engine_statistics
FROM `my_project_id.region-eu.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS`
WHERE 1=1
    and bi_engine_statistics.bi_engine_mode = 'FULL'
    and total_bytes_processed = total_bytes_billed
    and total_bytes_processed > 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your second question: I noticed that too and discussed it with Google a while ago, please find an excerpt of their answer below:

> during join, one side of the join was reading from the table and
> another side from shuffle. As BI Engine  does not support reading from
> shuffle, those stages are excluded from full/partial reporting.

Currently, this is not correctly represented in the information schema, but it is billed correctly. This is the (public fcticket https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/274899698?pli=1